# Local Network Permission dialog NOT showing up

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, networking, upnp

I'm working on a Flutter app for Philips Hue lights, so I obviously need to connect to the local network. I'm using `discover.quickDiscoverClients()` method from upnp plugin: https://pub.dev/packages/upnp Everything is working like a charm until I started Beta testing. None of my beta testers get the Local Network permission alert:
[image]
nor Local Network privacy permission in iPhone Settings -> app
[image]

I've already added `NSLocalNetworkUsageDescription` in plist file as well as `BonjourServices` and the Local Network Permission dialog is still NOT showing up for my beta users.

Also, the weird thing is it works on my phone and on my wife's phone as we are internal testers, however it does NOT pass for beta testers.

What shall I do, please to allow Local Networks for beta testers?

Could requesting multicast entitlement help? https://developer.apple.com/contact/request/networking-multicast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the reason was that there was a router in the local network that does NOT support UPnP => Therefore, this dialog will NOT even be triggered.